# События компонента TcxDBLookupComboBox

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe7

Работаю с компонентами `DevExpress`, в частности сейчас с компонентом `TcxDBLookupComboBox`. Пытаюсь найти аналог события OnChange, как у, например, компонента ComboBox. Хотелось бы добиться, чтобы по событию выбора пункта из списка, возвращался мгновенно код.

Неизменно получаю лишь код первого значения списка:

```
ShowMessage(TcxDBLookupComboBox1.DataBinding.Field.AsString);
```

Кто знает как это решается?

Comment: Никто не подскажет, как же получить событие выбора данного компонента? Проблема в том, что я не могу даже код просмотреть компонента, а следовательно переписать его. Там все защищено от изменений. Потому нужен качественный совет от тех кто работал с этим.

Answer (score 1):

На `TcxDBLookupComboBox` пишем, чтоб синхронизировался с `dataset` и брать `OnChange` из `dataset`.